# Need help grasping RelaxngValidatingReader in Commons.Xml.Relaxng

Tags: xml, relaxng, relaxng-compact

Environment: RelaxngValidatingReader .Net 2.0 Framework

I can't seem to get the validator to equal false, no matter how much I change the xml around. Am I missing some concept here?

**Resource**
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Commons.Xml.Relaxng

**rnc compact format**

```
start = root
root = element root { parent1* & parent2* }
parent1 = element parent1 { element field { attribute usecase_123 {text} } }
parent2 = element parent2 { element field { attribute usecase_AAA {text} } }
```

**xml instance**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <parent1>
    <hello/>
  </parent1>
</root>
```

**Main Program**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RncParser parser = new RncParser(new NameTable());
    TextReader source = new StreamReader("test.rnc");
    RelaxngPattern grammar = parser.Parse(source);

    XmlReader instance = new XmlTextReader("XMLFile1.xml");
    RelaxngValidatingReader reader = new RelaxngValidatingReader(instance, grammar);
    Console.WriteLine("Was the xml valid? {0}", reader.Read());
}
```

Comment: It seems like the best place to get help with this is probably the Mono-list mailing list http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-list I see on that list there’s been at least one previous discussion about RelaxngValidatingReader: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2014-October/051293.html http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2014-October/thread.html#51293

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat `Read()` until End-of-file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RncParser parser = new RncParser(new NameTable());
    TextReader source = new StreamReader("test.rnc");
    RelaxngPattern grammar = parser.Parse(source);

    XmlReader instance = new XmlTextReader("XMLFile1.xml");
    RelaxngValidatingReader reader = new RelaxngValidatingReader(instance, grammar);
    try {
        while (!reader.EOF) {
            reader.Read();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("validation succeeded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("validation failed with message:");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```